# com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: The API returned an error code: 404

Tags: box

I used function to create metadata with template. but it throw exception
com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: The API returned an error code: 404

```
createMetadata(typename, scope, metadata);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it seems to work.

```
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, "113280761775");
file.createMetadata(new Metadata().add("/test", "test"));

Metadata metadata = file.getMetadata();
System.out.println("printing out meta-data: " + metadata.get("/test"));
```

Comment: there no problem when we create metadata on file with "global" scope.
In this case i had created Metadata Template with fields String, number or Date. But it throw BoxException with code 400 when assigning with field is number. Example: 
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.add("/title", "title");
        jsonObject.add("/author", "author");
        jsonObject.add("/amount", 10);
        Metadata customerMetaData = new Metadata(jsonObject);
        uploadedFile.createMetadata("TemplateTest", customerMetaData);

with TemplateTest has field 'amount' is Number